# Input button image color

Tags: css

How to set the color images in a snap? I can not find the property of how this can be done.

There is a button in which there is a picture.

```
.button {
        background: url('../image/arrow.png') 189px no-repeat; /* картинка */
        background-color: #ff5c36; /* цвет кнопке*/
        color:  #ffffff; /* цвет текста в кнопке*/
        width: 100px;
    }

<input class="button" type="button" value="Send">
```

I don't understand how to add image in code.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to change the color of the arrow?

Comment: try input type image

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683528/embed-image-in-a-button-element)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined 189px which is taking `backgound-position`.

The css rule for background

```
background: background-color background-image background-repeat background-attachment background-position;
```

There is not inline property for `background-size`. Because `background-size` was introduced late in css3.

So you can define with `background-position` / `background-size`.

```
background: background-color background-image background-repeat background-attachment background-position/background-size;
```

Or it's better to use: `background-size` below after background property.

```
background: background-color background-image background-repeat background-attachment background-position;
background-size: width height; // Yes in background-size first one is width and 2nd is height
```

example:

```
background: url('image.png') no-repeat right center/14px;
```

or

```
background: url('image.png') no-repeat;
background-position: right center;
background-size:14px;
```

```css
.button {
        background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-right-b-128.png') no-repeat right center/14px;
        background-color: #ff5c36; /* цвет кнопке*/
        color:  #ffffff; /* цвет текста в кнопке*/
        width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<input class="button" type="button" value="Send">
```