# Image does not trigger script

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple dropdown button with image inside it:

By clicking on dropdown button, dropItems() is called, which displays list items:

```js
    function dropItems() {
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }
        window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn') || !event.target.matches('#dropdownicon')) {

            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="dropItems()" class="dropbtn"><img id="dropdownicon" src="img/dropdown.png" height="25" onclick="dropItems()"></button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As you can see, I have also applied onclick event on image inside button, because it blocks button's onclick when you click directly on image.

The problem is that when I click on image, nothing happens.

Comment: include CSS, i recommend using the Insert Code tool in StackOverflow.  They making a working example so someone can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have an `onclick` in the button as well as the nested image element, which both call the same function and since that function has a `toggle` in it, the second call could wind up reversing the toggle of the first call.

Second, don't use inline HTML event attributes in the first place (**[here's a long list of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** why).

But, the real issue is the layering of the nested image inside of the button, which can obstruct the button from being the event target. **The solution is to not use a `button` at all and just style the image to look like a `button` and code it to act like a button.**

Lastly, if you simply set a class on the drop down list that initially hides the list, the code becomes much simpler:

```js
// Get references to the HTML elements we will need:
var dd = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
var img = document.querySelector("img");

// Set up the click event handler for the image:
img.addEventListener("click", dropItems);

// Set up the click event handler for the window
window.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  // If anything except the image was clicked...,
  if(evt.target !== img){
    // Hide the list
    dd.classList.add("hide");
  }
});

function dropItems() {
  dd.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```css
/* This will be applied to the list by default */
.hide { display:none; }

/* Style the image to make it look like a button: */
img { 
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;;
  border:1px solid #808080;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #a0a0a0;
  height:25px;
}

/* Change the style when the image is clicked to make it 
   look like it's a button being clicked. */
img:active {
    box-shadow:-1px -1px 1px #606060;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <!-- Don't use HTML to style elements. That's CSS's job. -->
  <img id="dropdownicon" class="dropbtn"
       src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1d/3b/8e/1d3b8e3c20793a25a32de080956cb41a--emoji-faces-smiley-faces.jpg">

  <!-- Note that the list has the "hide" class applied by default -->
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content hide">
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't work because images are not allowed in buttons. Here is a possible solution for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8683553/1751277

Comment: This isn't the deal, even if image is outside button, it still does nothing

Comment: Of course images are allowed as child elements to the `button` element.

Comment: From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)** "`<button>` elements are much easier to style than <input> elements. You can add inner HTML content (think `<em>`, `<strong>` **or even `<img>`**), and make use of `:after` and `:before` pseudo-element to achieve complex rendering while `<input>` only accepts a text value attribute."

Comment: Yes, you're right. I reasoned it because I had a problem with images in buttons in the past.