# Transparent Image Button

Tags: html, css, button

I made a button that opens to make sort of like a drop-down page. I also made a button to retract the page and put an image in it, but I want to make the button not show up, only the image. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<button onclick="close1()"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-material-4-1/26/368-512.png" alt="close" width="30"></button>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/poJPjpr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed image in a <button> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683528/embed-image-in-a-button-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution: only set transparent border and background for it.

```css
button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="transparent_button" onclick="close1()"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-material-4-1/26/368-512.png" alt="close" width="30"></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution:

```css
.transparent_button {
     background-color: transparent;
        border: 0px;
    }
```

```html
  <button class="transparent_button" onclick="close1()"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-material-4-1/26/368-512.png" alt="close" width="30"></button>
```

But for a better-written solution, you can try this (this won't force CSS uslessly):

```html
<img onclick="close1()"src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-material-4-1/26/368-512.png" alt="close" width="30">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the button, but just the image to be clicked on you can leave the button out and use the following code:

```
<img onclick="close1() src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-material-4-1/26/368-512.png" alt="close" width="30" />
```

Maybe, if you want a border you can box it and style that:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="imageBox">
<img onclick="close1() src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-interface-material-4-1/26/368-512.png" alt="close" width="30" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.imageBox{
    border:1px solid #c1c1c1;
    /* Other additional styles */
}
```