# download image via image-weblink

Tags: html

i'm trying to code a download button that uses an image-weblink such as: https://i.redd.it/f88s1u3g7ma41.jpg
in order to download that same image
i've searched many code exchange sites but can't find any that work for image-weblinks, 
example of one of the simpeler tries:
[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLkHS.png)

this is one of many failed attempts, the point is that the source has to be a weblink.

Comment: Please use the embedded code snippet tool to better explain the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed image in a <button> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683528/embed-image-in-a-button-element)