# ASP .NET Application - add image instead of text to to asp-route-returnUrl

Tags: html, css, asp.net, button

I would like to add some picture to route instead of text.
How can I do that?

My example looks like :

```
 <form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
        <button id="logout" type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-white">Logout</button>
    </form>
```

I want to have an image in Logout text place.
I can't figure it out. Can someone help me with that simple thing.. ? How can I replace button with an image? I try a lot of img scr etc. But always something is wrong and it didn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do that, I prefer simply put an image into a button:

```
<button id="logout" type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-white">
    <img src="logout_button.png">
</button>
```

See: [Embed image in a <button> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683528/embed-image-in-a-button-element)