# How to switch pictures by pressing the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning how to create websites. I want to build a simple theme switcher with HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I've done the theme switching part, but I want to change the picture in the button when I press it.

Here is my moon picture: (https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/6390/moon) and  here is my sun picture: (https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/304624/sun-light-theme).

Here is my code:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn_theme');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark_theme');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body.dark_theme {
  background-color: #2F3136;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #2F3136;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn_theme {
  text-align: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .15s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
  align-items: center;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #2f3647;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
}
```

```html
<p>text</p>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn_theme" id="btn_theme"><img src="../imgs/солнце.svg" /></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to accomplish this.

One way is to just get rid of the img tag and change the button's background image.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn_theme');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark_theme');
});
```

```css
.btn_theme {
  background: url('https://www.svgrepo.com/show/304624/sun-light-theme.svg');
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .15s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
  align-items: center;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #2f3647;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
}

.dark_theme {
  background: #ffaaff
}

.dark_theme .btn_theme {
  background: url('https://www.svgrepo.com/show/6390/moon.svg');
}
```

```html
<button class="btn_theme" id="btn_theme"></button>
```

Another solution is to use a data-attribute to store the current state and change the img tag's src value.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn_theme');
const icon = btn.querySelector('img');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark_theme');

  if (icon.dataset.theme == "light") {
    icon.dataset.theme = "dark";
    icon.src = "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/6390/moon.svg";
  } else {
    icon.dataset.theme = "light";
    icon.src = "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/304624/sun-light-theme.svg";
  }


});
```

```css
.btn_theme {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .15s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
  align-items: center;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #2f3647;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
}

.dark_theme {
  background: #ffaaff
}
```

```html
<button class="btn_theme" id="btn_theme"><img class="icon" data-theme="light" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/304624/sun-light-theme.svg"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `src` attribute of your image using [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

You could use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to switch between pictures. This would work for however many pictures you want to have. It is however not required for a two images as you could just use a boolean. Nevertheless here how you could do it using [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

```js
// All the pictures we want to switch between
const pics = [
  "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff",
  "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/dddddd/000",
  // "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/d420d4/000" // comment this out for a third pic
]
let curPicIdx = 0;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
  // when the page has loaded set the first picture
  const button = document.getElementById("mybutton");
  const img = document.getElementById("myimage");
  img.setAttribute("src", pics[curPicIdx])
  
  // whenever we click on the button change the picture to the next one
  button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    // calculate the index of the next picture using modular arithmetic
    curPicIdx = (curPicIdx + 1) % pics.length;
    console.log(`Setting pic ${curPicIdx}`);
    // set the next picture using the calculated index
    img.setAttribute("src", pics[curPicIdx]);
  })
})
```

```html
<button id="mybutton"><img id="myimage"/>
```

If you want to have three pictures, just add another URL within the array and it will switch between all three pictures.

> In general there are a lot of ways to embed images into buttons. You might wanna have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683528/embed-image-in-a-button-element).